# OpenLayers 3 Style Function for dynamic feature font setting

Tags: function, styles, openlayers

I am using php and mySQL to generate javascript for the vector layers and features. All is functionally working except I need to be able to control the feature text with zoom, which from my searches requires the use of a style function.

My issue is how/where do I create a function to set what is currently fixed as "font: 140/10 + 'px arial' " tied to the map zoom setting ?

My current design uses a php loop using the database to create the features with unique location and properties:

1) create the feature
2) set the style
3) push into the array iconFeatures0

```js
var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
 geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([-0.163741,51.507847], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')),
  p_title: 'Hyde Park Title',
  p_line1: 'Hyde Park',
  p_line2: 'Park information ...',
  lat: 51.507847,
  long: -0.163741,


});


iconFeature.setStyle(

              new ol.style.Style({
                  image: new ol.style.Icon(({
                        anchor: [0.5, 1.0],
                        anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
                        anchorYUnits: 'fraction',
                        opacity: 0.85,
                        src: 'test_map/marker_0.png',
                        size: [52,64],
                        scale:0.5,
                      })),
                  text: new ol.style.Text({
                        text: 'Hyde Park',
                        offsetY: -37.5,
                        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                            color: '#FF3300'
                        }),
                        font: 140/10 + 'px arial'
                    })
              }),

          );

        iconFeatures0.push(iconFeature); 


//On completion of the loop:

var vectorSource0 = new ol.source.Vector({ 
    features: iconFeatures0 
}); 

vectorLayer0 = new ol.layer.Vector({ 
    source: vectorSource0 
}); 

//setting up the map
var myOSMLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.OSM()
});



// Create latitude and longitude and convert them to default projection
var myMapcentre = ol.proj.transform([-0.140180,51.501811], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');       //$long,$lat
var myMapView  = new ol.View({
    center: myMapcentre,
    zoom: 14
  })




var myMap = new ol.Map({
  controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([
          new ol.control.FullScreen()
        ]),
  layers: [myOSMLayer, vectorLayer0],
  loadTilesWhileInteracting: true,
  target: document.getElementById('demoMap1'),
  view: myMapView
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to accomplish this, here is one of them.

First, it would be more efficient if you prepare the styles and simply apply them at different scale, so OpenLayers doesn't have to re-create the styles each time the zoom changes.

Then, instead of styling each feature individually, you would style the entire layer (you can still discriminate by feature "category" within the layer).

At last, you would benefit from the the option to consider the resolution when styling the layer:

```js
vectorLayer0.setStyle(function(feature, resolution) {
   return [new ol.style.Style({
       text: new ol.style.Text({
         font: resolution/1000+'px Calibri,sans-serif',
         text: "test",
         fill: fill
       })
     })];
  });
```

You would remove the code `iconFeature.setStyle( ...` from your code and put the above code after having created `vectorLayer0`

Comment: Thanks for reply. Perhaps unwisely, i have combined the styling and data as i have a dynamic text property set by the database for each icon, so can you suggest your other ways to achieve a result ?